# How to use multiple dictionaries in a listbox DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox

I am wondering if it is possible to use two dictionaries in a listbox data template. I want to use the value of Names in a textbox, and the value of EnabledNames for a check box. Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing it?

*Some example data would be:*

```
Dictionary<string, string> Names = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "4EG25","John" },
                {"923OT", "Joe" }
            };
            Dictionary<string, bool> EnabledNames = new Dictionary<string, bool>()
            {
                { "4EG25",false },
                {"923OT", true}
            };
```

*And how I want to use in a way like:*

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="359" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="673" Margin="0,0,-0.333,-0.333" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Names, Mode=OneWay}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=EnabledNames[ItemsSource.Key].Value}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemsSource.Value}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to create a simple view model class with a Name and an IsEnabled property? Then bind the ListBox to a collection of this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very hard, so I'd recommend you to create specific class as DataContext for your ListBox.

What you could try in your case:

1. WPF binding can be done only to properties (your dictionaries are now Fields, so your bindings won't work. Your ViewModel could be something like this:

   ```
   public class ViewModel
   {
       public ViewModel()
       {
           Names = new Dictionary<string, string>()
           {
               { "4EG25","John" },
               {"923OT", "Joe" }
           };
           EnabledNames = new Dictionary<string, bool>()
           {
               { "4EG25",false },
               {"923OT", true}
           };
       }

       public Dictionary<string, string> Names { get; set; }
       public Dictionary<string, bool> EnabledNames { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. In your xaml when you set DataTemplate, its DataContext is set to single entry of your ItemsSource. In your case this is KeyValuePair. Also you could use MultiBinding to bind to your EnabledNames dictionary and use converter to convert your Key to bool Value from EnabledNames:

   ```
   <Window x:Class="Test31641637.MainWindow"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test31641637"
           Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
           Name="mw">

       <Window.Resources>
           <ResourceDictionary>
               <local:MultiDictionaryConverter x:Key="multiDictionaryConverter" />
           </ResourceDictionary>
       </Window.Resources>
       <Window.DataContext>
           <local:ViewModel />
       </Window.DataContext>
       <ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Names}">
           <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <CheckBox >
                           <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                               <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiDictionaryConverter}" ConverterParameter="">
                                   <Binding Path="Key" Mode="OneWay"/>
                                   <Binding ElementName="mw" Path="DataContext.EnabledNames"/>
                               </MultiBinding>
                           </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                       </CheckBox>
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
                   </StackPanel>
               </DataTemplate>
           </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       </ListBox>
   </Window>
   ```

And IMultiValueConverter:

```
public class MultiDictionaryConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length == 2 && values[0] is string && values[1] is Dictionary<string, bool>)
        {/*
            ((Dictionary<string, bool>)values[1])[values[0] as string] =
                !((Dictionary<string, bool>)values[1])[values[0] as string];*/

            return ((Dictionary<string, bool>)values[1])[values[0] as string];
        }

        return false;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I suppose this is the easiest way to do it (but it is not easy) **and it won't work, because when you click on CheckBox in your ListBox, ConvertBack method will be called**, but it is **impossible** to convert back boolean value. So, again, the easiest way is to create specific class that represents single line of your ListBox:

```
public class Person
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a class that contains both values and use it as the ItemsSource

```
class Name
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<Name> TheNames
{
    get { return Names.Select(n => new Name {Value = n.Value, Enabled = EnabledNames[n.Key]}); }
}


<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TheNames, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Enabled}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```